# How to get e-mail ID in Qt C++ after an OAuth2 google authentication?

Tags: qt, oauth-2.0

My Qt based desktop application is giving certain feature open to those people who have valid google account. For that, I have implemented OAuth2 based login mechanism in my app. 
Major reference is this link:
http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/25/connecting-qt-application-google-services-using-oauth-2-0/
In a nutshell, this explains a way to authenticate a user using browser with OAuth2 protocol. Of course using QNetworkAuth class.
I am getting “Authentication GRANTED” reply as I have done OAuth2 properly. But I need to get the e-mail ID of the person logged. 
The final statement in this blog talks about something similar to my need. But that does not work with me. Giving 
How to get e-mail id of the person logged?

Comment: It does not work **how**?

Comment: Server replied "forbidden"

Answer (score 0):

We wrote about this in our post on [How To Authenticate with Google SSO in Qt](https://appfluence.com/productivity/how-to-authenticate-qt-google-sso/) and in one of the code blocks we left the code that you need. Some of the Google APIs have evolved since you wrote this, specifically the People API:

```
connect(this->google, &amp;QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted, [=](){
    const QString token = this->google->token();
    emit gotToken(token);

    // Alternatively, just use the token for your purposes
    auto reply = this->google->get(QUrl("https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/me}"));
    connect(reply, &amp;QNetworkReply::finished, [reply]() {
        qInfo() << reply->readAll();
    });
});
```